# open a modeldialog on submit of a form with all values of that form

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4.0 website that has a button on a screen. according to my requirement i have submit a hidden form that has some hidden values, on the click of that button. My requirement is that

I have to open a model dialog with all these hidden values.

Please give me some solution.

```
//under a Beginform of a view this button code is written

<input type="button" id="idBtnScan" name="btnName" value="Scan" onclick="javascript:subProcessURL()" /> 

//I have add this hidden form on click of this button
//@Model.UDConfig.sScanningURL = is the url of the another website's default page
//Model.UDConfig.listScanData (list) that contains all parameter that takes another website.

<form id="idFormSelect" action ="@Model.UDConfig.sScanningURL" method="post" >
<div class="makeHidden">
    @for(int i=0;i<Model.UDConfig.listScanData.Count;i++)
    {
        <input type="text" id="@Model.UDConfig.listScanData[i].sKey" name="@Model.UDConfig.listScanData[i].sKey" value ="@Model.UDConfig.listScanData[i].sValue" />
    }
    <input type="text" id="ASPUserSessionId" name="ASPUserSessionId" value="@Session.SessionID" />
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitDetails" />
</div>
</form>


<script type ="text/javascript" >
function subProcessID() {

    window.showModalDialog("@Model.UDConfig.sScanningURL", "#idFormSelect", "dialogWidth:700px;dialogHeight:500px;scroll:no;")
    $("#idFormSelect").submit();
}

</script>

 $("#idBtnScan")[0].onclick = function () {
        HideDivInfoNErrorMsg();
        ShowOverlay_Base();
        subProcessURL();
        @*$.ajax({
            //type: "POST",
            //url: "@Url.Action("GetSingleScanURL", "CreationOutward")",
            //success: function (data) {
                //window.showModalDialog(data, "", "dialogWidth:700px;dialogHeight:500px;scroll:no;")*@

                //functionality of view image
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("ActionViewImage", "CreationOutward")",
                    success: function (dataImage) {

                        HideDivInfoNErrorMsg();
                        if ((dataImage == "Image not found")
                            || (dataImage == "Image Folder not found")
                            || (dataImage == "Error in processing image")
                            || (dataImage == "Multiple Images found")) {
                            $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg")[0].innerHTML = "<div class=\"errormessage\"><span>".concat(dataImage, "</span></div>");
                            DisplayInfoNErrorMsg();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#divImgView")[0].innerHTML = dataImage;
                            HideDivInfoNErrorMsg();
                        }

                        HideOverlay_Base();
                    }
                })
                //View Image till here

            //}
        //}
           // )
    }
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Show us some code...

Comment: I have add snippet of code for your reference. for any query please ask me. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your button calls a javascript function called 'subProcessURL', but in your code there's only a subProcessID function. These do not match

Comment: thanks for your response but after making change the problem remain same.

Comment: what exactly is 'the problem' then? if you call subProcessID, the dialog will show and once it's closed, the form does submit...

Comment: actually when i click on button nothing happen in the screen. No model dialog window open after click on the button.

Comment: the code you've provided seems fine, apart from the fact that the function names do not match. Here is a working fiddle: jsfiddle.net/AnqXx. I don't have the sScanningURL property, but you get the idea, the modal opens anyway when you click the 'scan' button...

Comment: I have found one more key-point after making some changes it working fine. Actually i have found that there is an ajax function in the code that is running on the click of button. Because of this my java-script function is not calling on the click of button. Now I have placed the function call in that ajax function. Now another window is open fine with the url. Now my problem is this that all form value are not passing to that window control which are submit on the click of button.

Comment: I have already shared in the section of code you can easily check that